# Weird output when looking for sum of factorial of digits in smallest number == the given number

Tags: python, algorithm

```
#Function factorial
def fact(d):
  f=1
  for i in range(d,0,-1):
    f=f*i
  print(f"factorial {f}")
  return f

#Function for summation of factorial of digits
def f(n):
  s=0
  d=n%10
  s=fact(d)+s
  n=int(n/10)
  print(f"summing {s}")
  return s

l=[]
q=int(input("enter number of queries"))
print(q) 
n=int(input("enter the number to which you want to calculate"))
m=int(input("enter range"))
for i in range(1,n+1):
   l.append(i) #adding elements from 1 to n in list
   print(l[i-1])
   for j in range(1,m+1): 
    p=f(j) 
    if(l[i-1]==p):#element in list is equal to function (i.e sum of factorial of digits)
      l[i-1]=p #then assign p to list
      print(f"list {l[i-1]}")
      break  #then break the second loop
```

Like for eg:
For query 1
n= 3 and m=100

Till 1 to n
look in m for numbers whose sum of factorial of digits is equal to number in n

For eg :
5=25 ( as 2! + 5! = 2+ 120 = 122
1+2+2=5)

**Then break for the next i iteration but I don't know where I'm making the mistake.**

Comment: Please add comments into your code.

Comment: for eg:
For query 1 
n= 3 and m =100

In first loop 
i=1 
then 2nd  loop runs till m=100
1=1 (1!) the break the second loop

i=2
then 2nd loop runs till m=100
2=1 (1!)
2=2 (2!) then break the second loop

i=3
then loop runs till m=100
3=1
3=2
3=3
...
3=12 (as( 1! +2!)=3)
then break the second loop

Comment: No ,minimum no. like 12= 1!+2!=3 , 25=2!+5!=2+120=122=1+2+2= 5   so 12=3 and 25=5 this is what I want

Comment: Check my comment for eg minimum number whose  sum of the factorial of the digits

Comment: Yes it's the range

Comment: It may help you that the sum of digits of `x` can be found with `sum([int(d) for d in str(x)])`.

Comment: That literally turns `x` into a string (and thereby the base 10 representation) then adds the digits as numbers.

Comment: @btilly: Not quite. It is sum of digits of the factorials of the digits.

Comment: @CrawlCycle Ah.  I found the question as clear as mud.

Comment: You need to clarify this question further.  Add example input and output and the desired output.  Also read [ask]

Comment: It's done !! 

Answer (score 0):

Goal: Find the smallest `x` such that the sum of digits of the factorials of the digits of `x` is `n`.

Sample behavior:

```
Find the smallest x such that:
    the sum of digits of the factorials of the digits of x is n
Please provide n: 12
Please provide the maximal x to check: 10000
Trying 1:
    Sum of the digits of factorials of the digits of 1 is:
        digit_sum(1!)
        = digit_sum(1)
        = 1
...
Trying 4:
    Sum of the digits of factorials of the digits of 4 is:
        digit_sum(4!)
        = digit_sum(24)
        = 6
...
Trying 16:
    Sum of the digits of factorials of the digits of 16 is:
        digit_sum(1!) + digit_sum(6!)
        = digit_sum(1) + digit_sum(720)
        = 10
...
Trying 33:
    Sum of the digits of factorials of the digits of 33 is:
        digit_sum(3!) + digit_sum(3!)
        = digit_sum(6) + digit_sum(6)
        = 12
x is 33.
```

Source code:

```py
import math


def print_sum_eq(x):
    print(f"    Sum of digits of the factorials of the digits of {x} is:")
    msg1 = [f"digit_sum({d}!)" for d in str(x)]
    print("        " + " + ".join(msg1))
    msg2 = [f"digit_sum({math.factorial(int(d))})" for d in str(x)]
    fact_values_str = " + ".join(msg2)
    print(f"        = {fact_values_str}")


def digit_sum(x):
    return sum(int(d) for d in str(x))


def sum_fact_digit(x):
    """Calculate sum of factorials of the digits of x

    For example, when x = 25, the digits are 2 and 5. The sum of the
    factorials of the digits is 2! + 5! = 2 + 120 = 122.

    Parameters
    ----------
    x : int

    Returns
    -------
    digit_sum : int
        Sum of the factorials of the digits of x
    """
    s = 0
    print_sum_eq(x)

    # Loop over the digits of x
    for d in str(x):
        digit = int(d)
        digit_fact = math.factorial(digit)
        s += digit_sum(digit_fact)

    print(f"        = {s}")
    return s


def search(n, max_x=None):
    """Try to find x such that sum of factorials of the digits of x is n

    Parameters
    ----------
    n : int
    max_x : int, optional
        The function will search over x = 1, 2, ..., max_x

    Returns
    -------
    result : int or None
        If we find x, the result is x.
        If we can't find x, the result is None.
    """
    if max_x is None:
        max_x = int(10 ** n)
    for x in range(1, max_x + 1):
        print(f"Trying {x}:")
        sum = sum_fact_digit(x)
        if sum == n:
            return x
    return None


def main():
    print("Find the smallest x such that:")
    print("    the sum of digits of the factorials of the digits of x is n")
    n = int(input("Please provide n: "))
    max_x = int(input("Please provide the maximal x to check: "))
    x = search(n, max_x=max_x)
    if x is None:
        print("Cannot find such a x.")
    else:
        print(f"x is {x}.")


main()
```

Comment: This can be made much, much faster.  Good luck with your approach finding that the answer for 319 is 1336999999999999.

Comment: @btilly: Trying to guess what does the op actually want took too much time :) How would you make this faster? Solving integer programming problems usually requires using hueristic, which doesn't guarantee to find the optimal answer. I would be really interested to know your approach.

Comment: You can use dynamic programming.  We know that small digits will go before large ones, and we want to use the fewest possible digits.  Which means we can use a breadth first search to build up a dict `last_digit_in_sum` of the last term in the shortest sum of (sums of digits of factorials) that ges to any particular number.  And then just walk backwards through that data structure from your target number to get the digits.

Comment: How to prune the search tree? Each node has one branch for each of the 10 digits. It is dynamic programming on a 10 dimensional grid.

Comment: It is a simple breadth-first search and you only add a number to the `todo` list when nothing else reached it first.  That autoprunes it.

Comment: You mean to terminate a branch when a previous combination of digits give the same sum of factorial of digits. The problem is that the factorials of the digits are quite different. It takes 9 steps of 8! to reach the same sum as 1 step of 9!. I don't think that kind of pruning is enough.

Comment: It is enough if you do a simple breadth-first search.  Because for each number you reach, you only have to look at 10 new numbers.  You will likely overshoot your target before you hit but only by a fixed amount.  As a result the algorithm is `O(n)` where `n` is your target.

Comment: If I could post my code, I would.  But it only takes a couple of seconds to find that the answer for a million is a leading 1 followed by 37037 9s.  I think that's fast enough. :-)

Comment: faster: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64826841/speed-up-search-for-the-smallest-x-such-that-fx-target/64827297#64827297